# Find nested repeater on OnCommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am having a problem finding a nested Repeater using the OnCommand event. The nested Repeater (Rep3) has a LinkButton in the FooterTemplate, has some TextBoxes with data I need to send to SQL. The issue is that I need to reference the Repeater (Rep3) which contains the LinkButton inside the OcCommand event of the LinkButton. Below is my markup;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rep1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Rep2" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Rep3" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnCommand="LinkButtonSave_OnCommand" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I tried find the repeater like below but with no luck:

```
 protected void LinkButtonSave_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton LinkButtonSave = (LinkButton) sender;
        RepeaterItem riItem = (RepeaterItem) LinkButtonSave.NamingContainer;
        Repeater Rep3 = (Repeater) riItem.FindControl("Rep3");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see "RepQuestions" any where in your mark-up above, but if I understand correctly you are trying to find the repeater which is the parent of LinkButtonSave. Here is how you do that:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rep1.DataSource = new string[] { "Test" };
        Rep1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Rep1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater Rep2 = e.Item.FindControl("Rep2") as Repeater;
        Rep2.ItemCreated += Rep2_ItemCreated;
        Rep2.DataSource = new string[] { "Test" };
        Rep2.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Rep2_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater Rep3 = e.Item.FindControl("Rep3") as Repeater;
        Rep3.DataSource = new string[] { "Test" };
        Rep3.DataBind();
    }
    protected void LinkButtonSave_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton LinkButtonSave = (LinkButton)sender;

        // Here is the found repeater. The first parent returns the FooterTemplate
        Repeater Rep3 = LinkButtonSave.Parent.Parent as Repeater;
    }
```

Comment: Thewisegod, I was actually referring to Rep3 like you explained. I have edited the question to reflect this fact. I am checking your solution and will mark your solution appropriately.

Comment: Thewisegod, you rock! Your solutions works and thanks for saving my day.